# mdc-image-list with loop in the image src

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, imagelist

I am trying to view a set of images.
My objective is in the image src to implement a function that individually fetches the images from another API.

My problem is when I log the console I see a duplication of results. Does anyone know the source of the problem and how can I solve it?

I leave below the example of duplicating the results, in fact they should only appear 8.

[image]

[**DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2ieuh2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

**HTML**

```
<ul class="mdc-image-list mdc-image-list--masonry masonry-image-list">
  <li class="mdc-image-list__item"
      *ngFor="let image of data">
   <img class="mdc-image-list__image"
        [src]="getImage(image.src)">
  </li>
</ul>
```

**.TS**

```
getImage(url) {
    console.log(url);
    return url;
  }
```

Comment: How is `data` being populated? Is it a static array like in the StackBlitz example, or populated from somewhere else? It's likely caused by the re-evaluation of the `getImage()` method with Angular's update cycle. I would recommend you iterate over `data` when it's initially populated, saving the results of the individual `getImage()` calls into another array. then you can just `*ngFor` over that array directly and it won't make multiple calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made my mind up about what the issue likely is. Per my comment, it's likely that the `GetImage()` method is being evaluated multiple times as part of Angular's update cycle.

I would iterate over the `data` array when it is first filled, doing your own singular evaluation of `getImage()`, saving the result:

```
public data: any[];

public ngOnInit(): void {
  const data = this.service.getDataSomehow();

  data.forEach((img: any) => {
    this.data.push(this.getImage(img.src));
  });
}
```

Then your template just changes slightly to be:

```
<ul class="mdc-image-list mdc-image-list--masonry masonry-image-list">
  <li class="mdc-image-list__item"
      *ngFor="let image of data">
   <img class="mdc-image-list__image"
        [src]="image">
  </li>
</ul>
```

I will note, however, that you should look into using the [DomSanitizer](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer) for dealing with your resource URLs.